# Count occurences of values in an array of objects

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm new to Javascript and doing some exercises I found online. Since I want to really understand how things work and why some approaches are better than others, I would appreciate some feedback why my approaches are bad (or good).

I have an XML and process it with the SAX parser to get "trending keywords". As an overall result, my function should return the 5 most popular ones. The result of my parsing itself is an array with 20 objects in the format

```
[{
  attributes: {}
  //children is just one big entry, separated by ';'
  children: ["Comey, James B;Federal Bureau of Investigation;Trump, Donald J;United States Politics and Government"]
  IsSelfClosing: false,
  name: 'ADX_KEYWORDS',
  parent: null,
  __proto__: {}
}]
```

Now my idea was, to pull out all those `children` values and store it in a new array

```
let flattenArr = keywords.reduce( (acc, cur) => acc.concat(cur.children), []);
```

As result I get an array (also length 20) in the format

```
[["Comey, James B;Federal Bureau of Investigation;Trump, Donald J;United States Politics and Government"],
["Trump, Donald J;Comey, James B;Federal Bureau of Investigation;United States Politics and Government"]]
```

To process the single values, I split the array

```
let mapArr = flattenArr
  .map( arr => arr.split(';') )
  .reduce( (acc, cur) => acc.concat(cur), [] );
```

and as a result, the new array of length 115 contains every single keyword separated. And here is the point where I don't know how to proceed. I tried the example from MDN(Array.Reduce) but didn't really know if (and how) I would be able to process these object.

```
//Result from MDN example, {value: quantity}
{ 'Alice': 2, 'Bob': 1, 'Tiff': 1, 'Bruce': 1 }
```

So I had the idea of creating an object for every keyword, with a property for its quantity

```
{
  key: keyword,
  count: n
}
```

and tried to accomplish this with

```
let countKeywords =  mapArrreduce( (allKeywords, keyword) => {
  if (allKeywords[0] != null && keyword in allKeywords[keyword]) {
    allKeywords[keyword].count++
  } else {
    allKeywords.push({
      keyword: keyword,
      count: 1
    })
  }
  return allKeywords;
}, []);
```

but my code doesn't work, and even after two days I still struggle to make it work, which made me post this question (which is kinda new for me, since I always found my answers on stackoverflow and therefore never had to ask a question myself)

Comment: your last snippet.... is it missing a `.`? I'd expect the {key: count} structure to be far easier to build/work with. Why couldn't you use the mdn example?

Comment: Your first object is missing some `,`, and what is the name of the variable? `cur`? What is `acc`? Would also help if you have more than a single entity of array data.

Comment: `To process the single values, I split the array` doesn't that snippet throw an error? your question is quite a bit unclear. The mdn example with your array flattened properly works just fine.

Comment: it must be  mapArr.reduce , youre missing a dot...

Comment: you are missing some `;`

Comment: Sorry for the late answer, had some ISP trouble ... @KevinB I couldn't figure out how to "filter" it (not talking about filter method here) because what "key" to search for? `{key1: 3}` and `{key2: 9}` looked harder to me than `{key: keyword1, count: 3}` and `{key: keyword2, count: 9}`because I thought I could just do "give me all objects with highest `count`". And sorry for missed `.` and `,`, didnt copy/paste it, wrote it new to flatten my structures a bit.

Comment: The problem is, with your structure you're going to have to loop through every object until you find the one that has a matching key, where as if you used an object you could get to the correct target key instantly. That of course won't make it easier to do grouping/filtering, such as give me all keys who have a count less than n. (but also doesn't make it harder)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Should be able to do it like this. Since you're using multitudes of nested arrays, you end up having to flat map (reduce + concat) twice. You could simplify the readability of it by converting that to a prototype method.

```
let flattenArr = [
    ["Comey, James B;Federal Bureau of Investigation;Trump, Donald J;United States Politics and Government"],
    ["Trump, Donald J;Comey, James B;Federal Bureau of Investigation;United States Politics and Government"],
    ["Trump, Donald J;Comey, James B;Federal Bureau of Investigation;United States Politics and Government"],
    ["Trump, Donald J;Comey, James B;Federal Bureau of Investigation;United States Politics and Government"]
]

let mapArr = flattenArr.reduce((a, b) => a.concat(b)).map(words => words.split(";")).reduce((a, b) => a.concat(b))

let orderedCount = mapArr.reduce(function (acc, cur) {
  if (typeof acc[cur] === 'undefined') {
    acc[cur] = 1;
  } else {
    acc[cur] += 1;
  }

  return acc;
}, {})

console.log(orderedCount)
```

Output:

```
{ 'Comey, James B': 4,
  'Federal Bureau of Investigation': 4,
  'Trump, Donald J': 4,
  'United States Politics and Government': 4 }
```

---

Here's the flatMap as a prototype ext:

```
Array.prototype.flatMap = function(lambda) { 
    return Array.prototype.concat.apply([], this.map(lambda)); 
}
```

Then use it:

```
let mapArr = flattenArr.flatMap(a => a).map(words => words.split(";")).flatMap(a => a)
```

Comment: Sorry for late answer, ISP trouble ... Since I'm a JavaScript beginner, what exactly is the "use" of that/a prototype method? Of course I read about prototype methods, but so far couldn't understand the "use" of it.

Comment: It's basically just an extension to the Array class that allows you to perform and chain functions on arrays.

Answer (score 0):

```
let countKeywords =  mapArr.reduce( (allKeywords, keyword) => {//typo <==
 var elem=allKeywords.find(el=>el.keyword===keyword);//its an array so allKeywords[keyword] wont work...
  if (elem) {
      elem.count++
  } else {
    allKeywords.push({
      keyword: keyword,
      count: 1
   })
 }
 return allKeywords;
}, []);
```